# Using Logitech Camera to capture Raspberry Pi Car

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

This is a program used to capture a moving Raspberry Pi Car. Instead of using a Raspberry Pi Camera, I'm using a Logitech camera, and am unsure of how to modify my code.

I encounter the following errors

> "camera is not enabled. try running 'sudo raspi-config' " picamera.exc.picameraerror: camera is not enabled. try running 'sudo raspi-config' and ensure that the camera has been enabled.

Here's my code below. Thanks for all your help!

```
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import cv2
import serial
import syslog
import time
import numpy as np
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

# 定義捕捉的畫面尺寸

width = 320

height = 240

tracking_width = 40

tracking_height = 40

auto_mode = 0

#如下定義小車前後左右的功能函數

def t_stop():

    GPIO.output(11, False)

    GPIO.output(12, False)

    GPIO.output(15, False)

    GPIO.output(16, False)

def t_up():

    GPIO.output(11, True)

    GPIO.output(12, False)

    GPIO.output(15, True)

    GPIO.output(16, False)

    time.sleep(0.05)

    GPIO.output(11, False)

    GPIO.output(12, False)
    
    GPIO.output(15, False)

    GPIO.output(16, False)

    time.sleep(0.3)

def t_down():

    GPIO.output(11, False)

    GPIO.output(12, True)

    GPIO.output(15, False)

    GPIO.output(16, True)

def t_left():

    GPIO.output(11, False)

    GPIO.output(12, True)

    GPIO.output(15, True)

    GPIO.output(16, False)

    time.sleep(0.05)

    GPIO.output(11, False)

    GPIO.output(12, False)

    GPIO.output(15, False)

    GPIO.output(16, False)
    
    time.sleep(0.3)

def t_right():

    GPIO.output(11, True)

    GPIO.output(12, False)

    GPIO.output(15, False)

    GPIO.output(16, True)

    time.sleep(0.05)
    
    GPIO.output(11, False)

    GPIO.output(12, False)

    GPIO.output(15, False)

    GPIO.output(16, False)

    time.sleep(0.3)

def t_open():

    GPIO.setup(22,GPIO.OUT)

    GPIO.output(22,GPIO.LOW)

def t_close():

    GPIO.setup(22,GPIO.IN)

def check_for_direction(position_x):

    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

    GPIO.setwarnings(False)

    GPIO.setup(11,GPIO.OUT)

    GPIO.setup(12,GPIO.OUT)

    GPIO.setup(15,GPIO.OUT)

    GPIO.setup(16,GPIO.OUT)

    GPIO.setup(38,GPIO.OUT)
    

    if position_x == 0 or position_x == width:
        print('out of bound')
        t_stop()

    if position_x <= ((width-tracking_width)/2 - tracking_width):
        print ('move right!')
        t_right()

    elif position_x >= ((width-tracking_width)/2 + tracking_width):
        print('move left!')
        t_left()
    else:
    #print ('move front')
        t_up()

# initialize the camera and grab a reference to the raw camera capture

camera = PiCamera()

camera.resolution = (width, height)

camera.framerate = 32

rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(width, height))

rawCapture2 = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(width, height))

# allow the camera to warmup

time.sleep(0.1)

# set the ROI (Region of Interest)

c,r,w,h = (width/2 - tracking_width/2), (height/2 - tracking_height/2), tracking_width, tracking_height

track_window = (c,r,w,h)

# capture single frame of tracking image

camera.capture(rawCapture2, format='bgr')

# create mask and normalized histogram

roi = rawCapture2.array[r:r+h, c:c+w]

hsv_roi = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_roi, np.array([0,30,32]), np.array([180,255,255]))

roi_hist = cv2.calcHist([hsv_roi], [0], mask, [180], [0,180])

cv2.normalize(roi_hist, roi_hist, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)

term_crit = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 80, 1)

# capture frames from the camera

for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format='bgr', use_video_port=True):

# grab the raw NumPy array representing the image, then initialize the timestamp

# and occupied/unoccupied text

    image = frame.array

# filtering for tracking algorithm

    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    dst = cv2.calcBackProject([hsv], [0], roi_hist, [0,180], 1)

    ret, track_window = cv2.meanShift(dst, track_window, term_crit)

    x,y,w,h = track_window

    cv2.rectangle(image, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), 255, 2)

    cv2.putText(image, 'Tracked', (x-25, y-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2)

# show the frame

    cv2.imshow("Raspberry Pi RC Car", image)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    check_for_direction(x)

    time.sleep(0.01)

# clear the stream in preparation for the next frame

    rawCapture.truncate(0)
```

Comment: Just curious: does this code work with the Raspberry Pi camera; Have you tested it?

Answer (score 0):

you really should start some extra test and see if you understand the suggested openCV.

you could start with this

```
    import cv2

print('cv2 version is ' + str(cv2.getVersionString()))


def capture_config(camera_port=0):
    frame_height = 480
    frame_width = 640

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_port)
    cap.set(3, frame_width)
    cap.set(4, frame_height)
    if not cap.isOpened():
        print('Unable to read camera feed')
        return False
    return cap


cap = capture_config()
while cap:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('captured frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score -1):

Rather than using picamera module, which is exclusively for the RPI camera as per the documentation (which you can find here: https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/faq.html)

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/webcams/

You should be using openCV. an example is provided in this link:

https://medium.com/propelland/raspberry-pi-tutorial-on-using-a-usb-camera-to-display-and-record-videos-with-python-a41c6938f89f

Comment: I have used this lens in other programs before and it works normally

Comment: I’m wondering if it’s necessary to change the code. Does anyone know how to change the code?

Comment: I believe you need to change the code, check the first link attached, or google the module fswebcam to see the code changes. As you can see here: https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/faq.html pycamera can only be used with the RPI camera

Comment: Do you know how to modify

Comment: Please check this link. It has an example: https://medium.com/propelland/raspberry-pi-tutorial-on-using-a-usb-camera-to-display-and-record-videos-with-python-a41c6938f89f

Comment: I know that  cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  can detect the camera, but I don’t know how to change it

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think I am able to help you much beyond the example, which should have the method. If you face any issue changing it, you can always post a new question; however outside of rewriting your code with the new method in mind, I am unable to do so. (Which is not our purpose in Stackoverflow, we are always happy to help here, but we can't write your whole code, rather we can just give guidance!)

Comment: This problem has troubled me for a long time, I still can't modify it